# Manhwa in which a princess kills her tyrant brother for the male lead, because the royal family has a blessing that their killer dies too

Tags: story-identification, manga

I don't know. I read it, but have been looking for it for months.

I think the prologue or 1st chapter was where the princess beheaded her tyrant brother, the king, while he sat on the throne. She kicked him off it and sat herself down. She waits as the family blessing kills her off and she listens to the rebellion happening outside.

The male lead is the duke, her husband and the leader of the rebellion. He comes in and sees her dying and she tells him "sorry" for killing the brother, but she can't let him die of the blessing, so she did it instead, because she's always loved him.

Then I think there's flashback of her telling her brother she likes the duke, then them getting married, then the king telling the duke his family's dead.  Then back to her dying; she wishes him a happy life. And then I think there's regression somewhere.

I only remember that she has long hair and the throne room was dark even if outside was sunny. There's a shot of the tyrant king's body on the ground beside the throne.

Answer (score 3):

Is this ***[Carnephelia's Curse Is Never Ending](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/carnephelias-curse-is-never-ending)***...?

> Princess Carnephelia was unloved and neglected until she met Helis, her first love. However, under the evil plots of her stepbrother Prince lanfried, she ended up destroying the only boy she ever loved. Devastated by what she had done, the princess swears revenge... even if it entails her life being cursed for eternity.

In the first chapter, Carnephelia Hellsdante, the second princess of the Hellsdante Empire, stabs and beheads her manipulative half-brother, Emperor Ianfried Hellsdante, while he sits on the throne.

> [image: "Carnephelia's Curse Is Never Ending," chapter 1, page 1-4.]

She knows that in doing so, she's now cursed to die due to a blessing placed on the family by God, but considers that a price worth paying in order to end his life and protect her husband, Duke Helis Svenbach, who was leading a rebellion to kill the Emperor himself. He arrives in the throneroom shortly afterwards to find her dying on the throne.

> [image: "Carnephelia's Curse Is Never Ending," chapter 1, page 19-21.]

After dying, Carnephelia wakes up in the body of her much younger self, and sets about changing her future.